# How to generate all distinct combinations (where input elements are repeated) in Python(using Itertools)?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have a set of numbers `[1, 2, 4, 1]`. Now, I want to generate all possible combinations from this set of size k (example k = 3). All the generated output sets must not be duplicate

Example : `[1, 2, 1]` and `[2, 1, 1]` are the same sets but they should not be selected. Only one of them should appear. Is it possible using combinations from itertools in Python?

```
import itertools
x = [1, 2, 1]
print([p for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=3)])
```

I have tried using itertools.product but it doesnt work and 
using combinations from itertools is getting duplicates

I have tried using itertools.combinations
`print([p for p in set(itertools.combinations(x, r=3))])`

If I give the following input

```
  x =  [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
```

The ouput generated for r = 3 is

```
[(0, -1, -4), (-1, -1, -4), (-1, 1, -4), (0, 2, -1), (-1, 0, 2), (-1, 2, -4), (0, 1, 2), (2, -1, -4), (-1, 0, -1), (0, 1, -4), (1, 2, -4), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 1, 2), (0, 2, -4), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 2, -1), (1, 2, -1), (0, 1, -1), (-1, 0, -4), (1, -1, -4)]
```

`(-1, 0, 1)` and `(0, 1, -1)` are duplicate sets with same combinations. I am not sure how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), and we can easily obtain the combinations of these with the `sympy` module.

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_combinations

list(multiset_combinations([1, 2, 4, 1], 3))
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 4]]
```

And here is the example by @EdedkiOkoh:

```
x = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
list(multiset_combinations(x, 3))
[[-4, -1, -1],
    [-4, -1, 0],
    [-4, -1, 1],
    [-4, -1, 2],
    [-4, 0, 1],
    [-4, 0, 2],
    [-4, 1, 2],
    [-1, -1, 0],
    [-1, -1, 1],
    [-1, -1, 2],
    [-1, 0, 1],
    [-1, 0, 2],
    [-1, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's [set datatype](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to remove those duplicates since sets will only contain the unique combinations:

```
import itertools as it
x = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]

permutations = [p for p in set(it.combinations(x, r=3))]
print(permutations)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 2),
 (-1, 1, -1),
 (-1, 2, -1),
 (0, -1, -4),
 (-1, -1, -4),
 (-1, 1, -4),
 (-1, 2, -4),
 (2, -1, -4),
 (1, 2, -4),
 (-1, 0, 1),
 (1, 2, -1),
 (-1, 0, -4),
 (-1, 0, 2),
 (-1, 0, -1),
 (-1, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, -4),
 (0, 2, -1),
 (0, 1, -4),
 (1, -1, -4),
 (0, 1, -1)]
```

Then use can use the following line:

```
unique_permutations = set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in permutations)
```

Output:

```
{(-4, -1, -1),
 (-4, -1, 0),
 (-4, -1, 1),
 (-4, -1, 2),
 (-4, 0, 1),
 (-4, 0, 2),
 (-4, 1, 2),
 (-1, -1, 0),
 (-1, -1, 1),
 (-1, -1, 2),
 (-1, 0, 1),
 (-1, 0, 2),
 (-1, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about getting the combinations and then taking only the unique ones by keying a dictionary with the [`frozenset`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/frozenset) result of the combinations. This will only use generators until creating the `dictionary`.

```
combs1, combs2 = itertools.tee(itertools.combinations(x, r=3))
res = list(dict(zip(map(frozenset, combs1), combs2)).values())
```